# Flex - Prevent Copy Event in TextArea with Scroll

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I would like to disable copy event in the TextArea I'm using. To achieve so I added the following code block:

```
function initTA(){
    var tf:IUITextField = body.mx_internal::getTextField();
    tf.enabled = false;
}

<mx:TextArea id="body" creationComplete="initTA()" .../>
```

This is working fine unless the text area has lots of text inside in which case a scroll bar appears. After the scroll bar is being used by the user, the text area stopped blocking the copy event.

By the way, I am using text area for display purposes since I use rich text area format.

Appreciate your help
Thanks!
Uri

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just set <code>selectable=false</code>? [(documentation)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html#selectable) Also, in general, it's a bad practice to use <code>mx_internal</code> properties and methods - they're not really meant to be accessed publicly and their behaviour can be changed without warning.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? How can you still copy text if you can't select it?

Comment: I think that if selectable="false" is not working then you probably have bigger problems...

Comment: @Uri So to be clear, you want to be able to select and navigate around the text, but not give the user the option to copy it? Also, what verison of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this issue is to disable the focus of the text-area component

```
function initTA(){
    var tf:IUITextField = body.mx_internal::getTextField();
    tf.enabled = false;
}

<mx:TextArea id="body" creationComplete="initTA()"  focusEnabled="false"  .../>
```

This way when the scroll bar is being used (due to lots of text in the text-area), the focus is not returned to the textarea and an indirect manner disables copy.